# 'this' is undefined in callback from directive

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that handles file uploads. The directive uses 'controller' and 'controllerAs' for dynamic controllers and in the 'link' function it fires callbacks that gets executed in the relevant dynamic controller.

The **problem** is when the callback is executed in the controller, *'this'* is undefined. How do I set the imageUrl in the controller?

Directive:

```
.directive('attachable', function(FileUploader) {
return {
  restrict    : 'E',
  transclude  : true,
  templateUrl : 'template.html',
  scope       : {},
  controller  : '@',
  controllerAs: 'uploadCtrl',
  name        : 'controller', 

  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var controller = scope.uploadCtrl;

      var uploader = scope.uploader = new FileUploader({
          url: controller.uploadUrl
      });

      // callbacks
      uploader.onAfterAddingFile = function(item) {
            controller.onAfterAddSuccess();
      };
   }
  };
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('core').controller('controller', ['$window', function($window){

    this.onAfterAddSuccess = function(item){

        if ($window.FileReader) {
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(item._file);

            fileReader.onload = function (fileReaderEvent) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    this.imageURL = fileReaderEvent.target.result;  // <- this is undefined
                }, 0);
            };
        }
    };
}]);
```

html:

```
<attachable controller="controller" ></attachable>
```

**EDIT:**

ste2425's answer resolves the 'undefined' error but why is *imageURL's* new value not available outside my controller i.e. the view?

updated controller:

```
...
fileReader.onload = function (fileReaderEvent) {

    this.imageURL = '';
    $timeout(function(){
        this.imageURL = fileReaderEvent.target.result;
    }.bind(this), 1);
};
...
```

html:

```
imageURL: {{ imageURL }}     <- this is still ''
<attachable controller="controller" ></attachable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will set the `this` of `$timeout` to the window.

You have a couple of options available. Either:

Bind the this context of your function:

```
    this.test = 'hiya';

   $timeout(function(){
        console.log('this WONT fail', this.test);
    }.bind(this), 1);
```

Or is using angular v1.4.1 or higher

```
   $timeout(function(ctx){
        console.log('this WONT fail', ctx.test);
    }, 1, true, this);
```

see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wopx3rtc/1/

Comment: Your suggestion resolves 'undefined' but check my edited question pls - imageURL's new value is not reflecting in my view. Any suggestions?

Comment: because your using `this` and `controllerAs` don't you have to reference it in your view with `uploadCtrl.imageURL`? I've never done it in directives but that how it works with `ng-controller`. If you want to use the syntax youve got in your view, scrap the controller as and replace `this` with your `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a side effect of JavaScript closures.  The most commonly used, direct way to solve this is to declare a constant variable that represents your controller, which can be referenced inside closures without being hidden by the closure itself.

```
angular.module('core').controller('controller', ['$window', function($window){
  var vm=this; //constant reference to controller
  ....
  fileReader.onload = function (fileReaderEvent) {
    vm.imageURL = '';
    $timeout(function(){
      vm.imageURL = fileReaderEvent.target.result;
    }, 0);
  };
  ....
```